# Convert DATEDIFF from SQL Server to redshift

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

I have script for SQL Server that I need to convert to redshift.

Here is part of it, where I have problem with

```
LEFT JOIN       
    (SELECT  
         cog.ClientId, 
         MAX(CASE me.metrickey WHEN 'contacts-employee_active_count_day_org' THEN mu.value ELSE 0 END) AS ActiveEmployees
     FROM    
         public.module_utilization mu
     JOIN    
         (SELECT  
              me.id,
              me.ChannelId + '-' + me.metrickey AS MetricKey
          FROM    
              public.module_metric me) AS me ON me.id = mu.metricid
     LEFT JOIN       
         public.contacts_client_organization cog ON cog.clientorganizationid = mu.organizationid
     WHERE   
         mu.dy >= DATEADD(Day, -30, GETDATE())
         AND me.metrickey IN ('contacts-employee_active_count_day_org')
     GROUP BY
         cog.clientid) metrics ON metrics.ClientId  = be.clientid
WHERE           
    be.organizationid = 65277
    AND be.timeworkedfrom >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    AND be.timeworkedfrom < TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', GETDATE()), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    AND be.isdeleted IS NULL
    AND be.isvoid IS NULL
```

At this line

```
AND be.timeworkedfrom >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

I get this error

> Invalid operation: function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", integer, timestamp without time zone) does not exist;

As I understood it because of `0`

How I can fix this stuff?

Comment: You have multiple SQL Server dependencies in your query.  Are you looking for a total refactor over to Redshift/Postgres?

Comment: It refactored at main, I only have trouble with row, mentioned above @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your highlighted `WHERE` clause logic is comparing `timeworkedfrom` to a date six months earlier than the first of the current month.  You may change this:

```
AND be.timeworkedfrom >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

to this:

```
AND be.timeworkedfrom >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '6 month'
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this